# Reduce the pattern matching

Tags: haskell

```
type ErrorOrValue = Either InterpreterError Value 

evaluateExpression :: [Value] -> IR.Expression -> ErrorOrValue

evaluateExpression as (IR.Application l r) 
    | Left _ <- arg = arg
    | Right (Partial ac b as) <- f = foo as f arg
    | Right _ <- f = Left NonFunctionApplication
    | otherwise = f
    where
        f = evaluateExpression as l >>= forceValue
        arg = evaluateExpression as r
```

I need to call `foo` with `f` and `arg` making sure that they are not `Left`.

Can I reduce the pattern matching and instead use binds and other monad operations?

Comment: Short answer: yes, Either is a monad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do`.  Your code checks `arg` before `f`, and `foo` appears to return an `ErrorOrValue`, so it does not need to be lifted into the `Monad`.  Also, the `as` that is passed to `foo` is that extracted from the `Partial`, not the argument to `evaluateExpression`.  Here is some completely untested code:

```
type ErrorOrValue = Either InterpreterError Value 

evaluateExpression :: [Value] -> IR.Expression -> ErrorOrValue

evaluateExpression as (IR.Application l r) =
    do arg <- evaluateExpression as r
       f <- evaluateExpression as l >>= forceValue
       case f of
           Partial ac b as -> foo as f arg
           otherwise -> Left NonFunctionApplication
```

Answer (score 5):

> I need to call `foo` with `f` and `arg` making sure that they are not `Left`.

For this, you can use the `Applicative` instance for `Either`.

```
foo <$> f <*> arg
```

or

```
liftA2 foo f arg
```

If `f` and `arg` are `Right` values, this will extract those, apply `foo` to them and give the answer back in a `Right` constructor. If either `f` or `arg` are `Left` values, that value will be returned (favoring the one from `f` if both are `Left`).